# How to use constant in class namespace as the array and template parameters?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, constants, static-members, c++98

I want to use the constant in class namespace as the size of a static array and the template parameter in another class. I have follow errors

```
// MS VS 2010 C++98
// A.h
class A
{
public:
 const static int someNumber;
};
// A.cpp
#include <A.h>
const int  A::someNumber = 5;

// B.h
#include <A.h>
class B
{
  std::bitset<A::someNumber> btst; // Error! C2975: '_Bits' : invalid template argument 

  double control[A::someNumber];   // Error! C2466: cannot allocate an array of constant size 0
};
```

How can I avoid them?

Comment: I might have misunderstood, but where are the errors?

Comment: @ForceBru In the code... (look at the comments)

Comment: You should put ";" after class A and B.

Comment: how do you expect `B.h` to know about a value set in `A.cpp` ?

Comment: Thank everybody for your corrections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is not that simple, because if you put all you declaration in one single file, it will compile and run correctly.

But just look at what compiler can see when it compiles B.h (assuming it is included in a main.cpp or B.cpp) :

`#include "A.h"` : ok it contains `const static int someNumber;` someNumber is a const int and its value will be given at link time

`std::bitset<A::someNumber> btst` : ok a bitset, the size is `A::someNumber` which is declared to be a const int, fine until here ... but wow, the value of the const is not known to the compiler at that time ! Let's assume it is 0
=> and you get both errors because compiler has no way to know the future value of `A::someNumber` !

Now we know that, the fix is simple : just write in A.h :

```
const static int someNumber = 5; // valid for a litteral const
```

Because now the compiler knows the value of `A::someNumber` at compile time and can correctly compile a file including B.h.

EDIT

You might be frightened at the idea of writing `const static int someNumber = 5;` in `A.h` because it could be included in many compilation units and you do not want to *define* same constant in many units. But in fact it is not a problem :

- at compile time, the compiler uses the value of `A::someNumber` any time it needs. And it notes that class A contains **one**  static field named `someNumber`.
- at link time, the linker ensure that there is only one instance of the `A::someNumber`. You can control that by printing the address of the static const field from different compilation units and you will get same value ... unless your developpement tools are seriously broken !

Comment: This is correct (plus one), but it will fail (I think) on any pre-MSVS2012 compiler due to their not correctly implementing the standard.

Comment: @Bathsheba : I've just tried it on MSVC 2008 and it works fine, even the part for the address of the static const int. But I don't have anything older to test ;-)

Comment: @SergeBallesta, I do not understand completely. At compile time the references to the class::constant are replaced not to its address, but to its value, so while compiling its value is 0. But only after linking its value is initiated. So, what is worked for MS VS 2008? If I add the initialization of class::const to B compile unit too, than I have the Error C2374: redefinition; multiple initialization.

Comment: @SergeBallesta, Oh, I'm sorry, thank you. I came to understanding. Assignment the value to class::constants works only for int.

Answer (score 4):

In C++98, you can't use `constexpr` as that wasn't introduced until C++11.

`double control[A::someNumber]` needs to be *compile-time* evaluable and your *definition* of `A::someNumber` resides in a different translation unit. That is what your compiler is complaining about.

However you can use an `enum`. I'm borrowing this technique from idioms used in template metaprogramming:

```
class A
{
public:
    enum {someNumber = 5};
}; /*and note this semicolon*/
```

Comment: what about `const static int someNumber = 5;`?

Comment: Perhaps you can explain that too in your answer. It is valid C++03 though, isn't it?

Comment: Not sure: I don't think you can initialise in a class declaration until C++11, and then only for certain types (of which `int` is one).

Comment: @Bathsheba: No, you could always initialise static constants of integer type (certainly in C++98, and probably earlier, but my memory doesn't stretch that far). C++11 adds initialisation of non-static members.

Comment: @Mike Seymour, MS VS 2010 returns the error, when I try to write:
`const static int someNumber = 5;` So @Bathsheba is right.

Comment: @so-olitary: Indeed, that particular compiler got quite a few things wrong, including that. It's valid according to the language standard though.

Comment: @so-olitary : I disagree with Bathsheba, because if you put everything in one single file it compiles and runs fine. `constexpr` in **not** required here.

Comment: @Serge Ballesta, yes, it is, but I cannot do it, because I will have the duplicates of this constants in different compilation units. My project is not so simple as the sample here.

Comment: @so-olitary : No you won't. But please see why in my answer below.